# Should a method on an object return a new copy of the object

Tags: oop

I'm seeing code in our legacy system where the class's public methods, clone the object, do the state mutation and return a new copy of the object.

It just feels wrong but just wondering if anyone knows of a known good reason to do this. Otherwise if anyone knows of a really bad reason to do this can you help out. I just need to arm myself with some arguments to and for this situation before I go and propose a big change.

Thanks

Sample Code

```
public Class MyClass
{
   public string MyProp { get; set; }
   public MyClass Cancel()
   {
        var newObj = this.Clone();
        newObj.Status = Status.Cancelled;
        return newObj;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am sure there is a reason why your legacy system does this.

Comment: Seems like application of [immutability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), which has some very good advantages (and also obvious disadvantages).

Comment: This is a change which can easily lead to breaks/bugs - so if you have no good tests and no business reason, do not do it. This has nothing to do with straight oo, it is more question about the protocol and the semantics of your classes if it makes more sense to return a new instances or perform a change on a copy.

Comment: Although if the object is supposed to be immutable it's weird that there's a public property setter...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a typical pattern with [*immutable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) objects, like `String` in Java or .Net for instance. By returning a new object with the change, references to the old object don't see the state change. Being able to rely on an object not changing can be very useful. Immutable objects come with a cost, of course, that every state change requires allocating a new instance.

---

As [MattDavey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522374/mattdavey) points out in a comment on the question, that sample code (assuming the missing bits added in) creates a class with *mutable* instances, because `MyProp`'s `set` is public. So it seems to ensure immutablility for `Status` but not for `MyProp`, which would be fairly unusual. It's more typical for an instance to be immutable, or not, but not partially so. I assume that's a by-product of editing the code for the question, though...

Comment: Strings are stored in pools which reduces the number of actual instances.

Comment: @Templar: Sometimes, and indeed, that's one of the advantages of immutable objects. Not by default in Java (except literals). I can't speak for .Net.